# Changing the contents of the same Java Activity by pressing the button

Tags: android

When I run the following code, first I see a red rectangle.

But I want to see a green rectangle first, and then when I press the button, next see a red rectangle in the same activity.

What is the solution?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
    Draw draw;
    Draw2 draw2;
    RelativeLayout linearLayout;
    public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        super.onCreate(s);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.t);
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

 draw = new Draw(this);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        draw.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        linearLayout.addView(draw);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Draw2.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        draw2 = new Draw2(this);
        draw2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        linearLayout.addView(draw2);
    }

}
```

**Draw.java**

```
public class Draw extends View {
    Paint paint;

    public Draw(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    }

@Override
    protected  void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    canvas.drawRect(50,30,100,120,paint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    }}
```

**Draw2.java**

```
public class Draw2 extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Draw2(Context context){
        super(context);
      paint = new Paint();
    }
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawRect(50,30,100,120,paint);
super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Draw2 is just a view not an activity,so Change MainActivity like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     Button button;
     Draw draw;
     Draw2 draw2;
     RelativeLayout linearLayout;
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams;

public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    linearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    draw = new Draw(this);

    layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 200);
    draw.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    linearLayout.addView(draw);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            draw2 = new Draw2(getApplicationContext());
            draw2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            linearLayout.addView(draw2);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: I used your code in **MainActivity** But in part of the **onclick** function and in the part of the this parameter, android studio says for me  **'Draw2(android.content.Context)' in 'com.exampedle.www.Draw2' cannot be applied to '(android.view.View.OnClickListener)'** and in the part of the **layoutParams** parameter in the same **onClick** function, android studio says for me **'Variable 'layoutParams' is accessed from within inner class. Needs to be declared final.**

Comment: I have made some changes ,try that.

Comment: Thank you.But I used this code also but when I run the **APK** file in my device, I see **stopped unexpectedly.Please try again**. Does the code run in your device well?

Comment: yes it works fine on my device ,only change i have made is chaning button name from button to button1. And you may run it on an emulator and find the error from logcat