# using DDMS in android studio and elimination of the common faults about it

Tags: android

please see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31223184/changing-the-contents-of-the-same-java-activity-by-pressing-the-button/31223798?noredirect=1#comment50475596_31223798).I asked a question in that and **@user2217535** said the code can run in device.But the code can not run in my device and emulator well.For this reason, I want to use **DDMS** to find the errors.But I do not know how do I use it because I see the following message in that:

**In Heap tab:**

> Could not create the view: org/jfree/experimental/swt/SWTUtils

**In Network Statistics:**

> Could not create the view:
>   org/jfree/experimental/chart/swt/ChartComposite

**In system Information:**

> Could not create the view:
>   org/jfree/experimental/chart/swt/ChartComposite

And finally I do not know how do I debug?

Comment: Do you updated your ADT ?

Comment: No.How do I do this update?

Comment: check if the issue is same as discussed here https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55454

Answer (score 0):

I did the following way and after that the errors was relieved:

**1- In android studio, go to SDK Manager**

**2- In SDK Manager, download the latest release of Android SDK tools and Android SDK Platform-tools.**

**3- reopen the android studio.**